# Cant add AddIdentity service in NET Core web api

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-core, .net-core, asp.net-core-webapi

I am using NET Core 3.1 + EntityFramework + PSQL. Trying to follow tutorials and msdn but my code doesnt work.

Here`s my **startup.cs**

```
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
    {            
        services.AddAuthentication(JwtBearerDefaults.AuthenticationScheme)
            .AddJwtBearer(options =>
            {                
                options.TokenValidationParameters = new TokenValidationParameters
                {
                   //params
                };
            });

        services.AddIdentity<ApplicationUser, IdentityRole>()
            .AddEntityFrameworkStores<MyContext>()               
    }
```

Here`s my **MyContext.cs**

```
public class MyContext : IdentityDbContext<ApplicationUser> 
{        
    public DbSet<Flowers> Flowers { get; set; }
    public DbSet<Post> Posts { get; set; }

    public MyContext() : base()
    {
        Database.EnsureCreated();
    }

    protected override void OnConfiguring(DbContextOptionsBuilder optionsBuilder)
    {
        optionsBuilder.UseNpgsql("Host=localhost...");
    }

    protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder modelBuilder)
    {
        base.OnModelCreating(modelBuilder);          

    }
}
```

Here`s my **ApplicationUser.cs**

```
 public class ApplicationUser : IdentityUser
{                
    public string SpecialNumber{ get; set; }

    public ICollection<Flower> Flowers { get; set; }        
}
```

When i try to run app i got an **exception** System.AggregateException: 'Some services are not able to be constructed'

> Some services are not able to be constructed (Error while validating the service descriptor 'ServiceType: Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity.ISecurityStampValidator Lifetime: Scoped ImplementationType: Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity.SecurityStampValidator`1[FlowersApp.Models.ApplicationUser]': Unable to resolve service for type 'FlowersApp.Models.MyContext' while attempting to activate 'Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity.EntityFrameworkCore.UserStore`9[FlowersApp.Models.ApplicationUser,Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity.IdentityRole,FlowersApp.Models.MyContext,System.String,Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity.IdentityUserClaim`1[System.String],Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity.IdentityUserRole`1[System.String],Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity.IdentityUserLogin`1[System.String],Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity.IdentityUserToken`1[System.String],Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity.IdentityRoleClaim`1[System.String]]'.) (Error while validating the service descriptor 'ServiceType: Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity.ITwoFactorSecurityStampValidator Lifetime: Scoped ImplementationType: Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity.TwoFactorSecurityStampValidator`1[FlowersApp.Models.ApplicationUser]': Unable to resolve service for type 'FlowersApp.Models.MyContext' while attempting to activate 'Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity.EntityFrameworkCore.UserStore`9[FlowersApp.Models.ApplicationUser,Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity.IdentityRole,FlowersApp.Models.MyContext,System.String,Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity.IdentityUserClaim`1[System.String],Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity.IdentityUserRole`1[System.String],Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity.IdentityUserLogin`1[System.String],Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity.IdentityUserToken`1[System.String],Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity.IdentityRoleClaim`1[System.String]]'.) (Error while validating the service descriptor 'ServiceType: Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity.IUserClaimsPrincipalFactory`1[FlowersApp.Models.ApplicationUser] Lifetime: Scoped ImplementationType: Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity.UserClaimsPrincipalFactory`2[FlowersApp.Models.ApplicationUser,Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity.IdentityRole]': Unable to resolve service for type 'FlowersApp.Models.MyContext' while attempting to activate 'Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity.EntityFrameworkCore.UserStore`9[FlowersApp.Models.ApplicationUser,Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity.IdentityRole,FlowersApp.Models.MyContext,System.String,Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity.IdentityUserClaim`1[System.String],Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity.IdentityUserRole`1[System.String],Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity.IdentityUserLogin`1[System.String],Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity.IdentityUserToken`1[System.String],Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity.IdentityRoleClaim`1[System.String]]'.) (Error while validating the service descriptor 'ServiceType: Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity.UserManager`1[FlowersApp.Models.ApplicationUser] Lifetime: Scoped ImplementationType: Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity.UserManager`1[FlowersApp.Models.ApplicationUser]': Unable to resolve service for type 'FlowersApp.Models.MyContext' while attempting to activate 'Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity.EntityFrameworkCore.UserStore`9[FlowersApp.Models.ApplicationUser,Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity.IdentityRole,FlowersApp.Models.MyContext,System.String,Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity.IdentityUserClaim`1[System.String],Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity.IdentityUserRole`1[System.String],Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity.IdentityUserLogin`1[System.String],Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity.IdentityUserToken`1[System.String],Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity.IdentityRoleClaim`1[System.String]]'.) (Error while validating the service descriptor 'ServiceType: Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity.SignInManager`1[FlowersApp.Models.ApplicationUser] Lifetime: Scoped ImplementationType: Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity.SignInManager`1[FlowersApp.Models.ApplicationUser]': Unable to resolve service for type 'FlowersApp.Models.MyContext' while attempting to activate 'Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity.EntityFrameworkCore.UserStore`9[FlowersApp.Models.ApplicationUser,Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity.IdentityRole,FlowersApp.Models.MyContext,System.String,Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity.IdentityUserClaim`1[System.String],Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity.IdentityUserRole`1[System.String],Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity.IdentityUserLogin`1[System.String],Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity.IdentityUserToken`1[System.String],Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity.IdentityRoleClaim`1[System.String]]'.) (Error while validating the service descriptor 'ServiceType: Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity.RoleManager`1[Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity.IdentityRole] Lifetime: Scoped ImplementationType: Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity.RoleManager`1[Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity.IdentityRole]': Unable to resolve service for type 'FlowersApp.Models.MyContext' while attempting to activate 'Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity.EntityFrameworkCore.RoleStore`5[Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity.IdentityRole,FlowersApp.Models.MyContext,System.String,Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity.IdentityUserRole`1[System.String],Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity.IdentityRoleClaim`1[System.String]]'.) (Error while validating the service descriptor 'ServiceType: Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity.IUserStore`1[FlowersApp.Models.ApplicationUser] Lifetime: Scoped ImplementationType: Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity.EntityFrameworkCore.UserStore`9[FlowersApp.Models.ApplicationUser,Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity.IdentityRole,FlowersApp.Models.MyContext,System.String,Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity.IdentityUserClaim`1[System.String],Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity.IdentityUserRole`1[System.String],Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity.IdentityUserLogin`1[System.String],Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity.IdentityUserToken`1[System.String],Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity.IdentityRoleClaim`1[System.String]]': Unable to resolve service for type 'FlowersApp.Models.MyContext' while attempting to activate 'Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity.EntityFrameworkCore.UserStore`9[FlowersApp.Models.ApplicationUser,Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity.IdentityRole,FlowersApp.Models.MyContext,System.String,Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity.IdentityUserClaim`1[System.String],Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity.IdentityUserRole`1[System.String],Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity.IdentityUserLogin`1[System.String],Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity.IdentityUserToken`1[System.String],Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity.IdentityRoleClaim`1[System.String]]'.) (Error while validating the service descriptor 'ServiceType: Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity.IRoleStore`1[Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity.IdentityRole] Lifetime: Scoped ImplementationType: Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity.EntityFrameworkCore.RoleStore`5[Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity.IdentityRole,FlowersApp.Models.MyContext,System.String,Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity.IdentityUserRole`1[System.String],Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity.IdentityRoleClaim`1[System.String]]': Unable to resolve service for type 'FlowersApp.Models.MyContext' while attempting to activate 'Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity.EntityFrameworkCore.RoleStore`5[Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity.IdentityRole,FlowersApp.Models.MyContext,System.String,Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity.IdentityUserRole`1[System.String],Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity.IdentityRoleClaim`1[System.String]]'.)

Cant find reason of this error. Are my clases inherited right?

App runs when i delete this part of code from **Startup.cs**

```
 services.AddIdentity<ApplicationUser, IdentityRole>()
            .AddEntityFrameworkStores<MyContext>()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add this to the top of your `ConfigureServices`
You need to tell the framework how could it create an instance of `MyContext`
 (Inject that Service)

```cs
 services.AddDbContext<MyContext>(options => /*<<<ADD YOUR DBCONTEXT CONFIGURATION >>>*/);
```

Answer (score 1):

You forgot to write this line in your `ConfigureServices` section

```
services.AddDbContext<MyContext>(options =>
        options.UseNpgsql("your connection string"));
```